# Paragraph column problems

Tags: tables, columns

This is maybe noob question but i have problem with paragraph column type 'm'. I was trying a lot of combinations but this problems i can not solve:

Text with in is not in the middle (vertical).

Also how is possilbe make newline in second column beetween `SSW` and `(LR)` with keep, functionality of horizontal padding (center)? I have tried several ways, but it did not work or text was off-center.

And at the end is possible set height on this paragraph column? (second line), but no any paddings just height in cm.

```
\begin{tabular}{
  | >{\centering}p{\dimexpr1.4cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  | >{\centering}p{\dimexpr1.4cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  | >{\centering}p{\dimexpr1.4cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  | >{\centering}m{\dimexpr7.6cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  | >{\centering}p{\dimexpr6.4cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  | >{\centering}p{\dimexpr1.2cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  | >{\centering}p{\dimexpr1.2cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  | >{\centering}p{\dimexpr1.2cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  | >{\centering}p{\dimexpr2.2cm-\arrayrulewidth\relax}<{\centering}
  |
}
\hline
Datum & SSW \footnotesize{(LR)} & SSW \footnotesize{(korriglert)} & I. Screening 8 + 0 bis 11 + 6 SSW & & FS & SSL & BPD & biometria \tabularnewline
\hline
& & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is wider than `\textwidth` and I have not adjusted it. Besides this, you have to use `m` column type to second and third columns.

```
\documentclass[margin=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{
  | P{1.4cm}
  | M{1.9cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | P{7.6cm}
  | P{0.4cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{2.2cm}
  |
}
\hline
Datum & SSW \par {\footnotesize(LR)} & SSW {\footnotesize (korriglert)} & I. Screening 8 + 0 bis 11 + 6 SSW & & FS & SSL & BPD & biometria \tabularnewline
\hline
& & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW `\footnotesize` is a switch and doesn't take arguments. Hence use `{\footnotesize (LR)}` instead of `\footnotesize{...}`

Comment: THX! But my document has this settings `\geometry{paper=a4paper, landscape, hmargin=28.5mm,vmargin=20mm}` but if i set 5th column back to 6,4cm everything is OK! Except SSW (LR) they are on the same line.

Comment: @LajdákMarek You can use `SSW \newline (LR)`

Comment: Yes this i was trying... there is newline but text is not centered. http://tinypic.com/r/2vv3qr8/8

Comment: @LajdákMarek Use `\par`, see the edit.